# Area 51 - can be the tooltip displayed with full description instead of the ellipsis symbol

Tags: discussion, feature-request, area-51, tooltips

In the proposal div, if the proposal description is exceeding around 240 characters, the ellipsis symbol is displayed. But when I hover over on the text there is no tooltip.

On hovering over the proposal title the tooltip is displaying but not with the full description, in the tooltip also the proposal description is displaying with the ellipsis.

So in the tooltip, can the detailed description be displayed?

[image: Example]